# How can I see all hidden folders in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

How can I see all folders under C:\users so I can backup and transfer all?

Comment: Go http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/394-hidden-files-folders-show-hide.html They have explained it with some pics and registry edits

Answer (score 5):

- Open Folder Options.
- Select **Show hidden files, folders, and drives**.
- Click **Apply**

Comment: Also of great help would be to disable `Hide extensions for known file types.` Depending on the level of hidden folders you need to see, you could also disable `Hide protected operating system files` however, modifying or moving anything about in system files is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Open any folder
Go to Tools>Folder Options>View> (press alt if you cannot see the 'Tools' option )

1. Select Show hidden files and folders
2. Uncheck hide extensions for known filetypes
3. Uncheck hide protected operating system files
   Now you can see pretty much every file/folder thats on your system